# Check if an input field is empty or not is not working properly in Cypress tests

Tags: input, field, cypress, is-empty, input-field

I got 2 step definitions in Cypress that check if an input field is empty or not (depends on how I build the sentence I setup with RegEx).

First my problem was, that cypress said the test failed because the input field is empty while it was not.

My defined steps:

```
/** We check if the input field with the given name is empty */
Given(/^The input field "(.*)" is (not )?empty$/, (inputFieldName, negation) => {
  if (negation === 'not ') {
    CypressTools.getByName(inputFieldName).should('not.be.empty');
  } else {
    CypressTools.getByName(inputFieldName).should('be.empty');
  }
});

/** We check if the input field with the given name is visible and empty */
Given(/^The input field "(.*)" is visible and empty$/, (inputFieldName) => {
  CypressTools.getByName(inputFieldName).should('be.visible').should('be.empty');
});
```

In my specific test cypress should check a value filled input field and the step is defined like that:
**The input field "XYZ" is not empty**

I can see, that the if-condition is working fine, so no problems on the definition or RegEx site.
But the test fails because Cypress say the input field is empty but it's not.

I suspect, that Cypress test the input fields for values between the input tags, but doesn't check for a value attribute in the input tag.

At least, I tried to add an **invoke('val')** in the step definition:

```
CypressTools.getByName(inputFieldName).invoke('val').should('not.be.empty');
```

and it works for the first step definition, but when I do that for the 2nd one aswell, cypress tests fail and tell me this:

```
Timed out retrying: You attempted to make a chai-jQuery assertion on an object that is neither a DOM object or a jQuery object.
The chai-jQuery assertion you used was:
  > visible
The invalid subject you asserted on was:
  > 
To use chai-jQuery assertions your subject must be valid.
This can sometimes happen if a previous assertion changed the subject.
```

I don't understand the problem here. Is this method valid with invoke() or is there a better solution to cover all cases?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Have you tried `cy.get(selector).should('not.have.value')` or `cy.get(selector).should('have.value', 'desiredValue')` Those work for me fine for Vue application. May be there is some specific for the plugins you use, or the framework you are using.

Comment: The problem here is, that I can't predict the value in the input field - is there any independent/universal case for 'have.value'?

Comment: The only solution I see is `CypressTools.getByName(inputFieldName).invoke('val').should(val => {expect(val.length).to.be.greaterThan(0)});

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem your error message is pointing to is that the subject being passed along the command chain in not appropriate for the next step,

```js
CypressTools.getByName(inputFieldName)
  .invoke('val')                      // changes subject to the text of the input
                                      // (not a DOM element)
  .should('be.visible')               // needs a DOM element
  .should('not.be.empty');
```

The surest way around it is to break the testing into two steps

```js
CypressTools.getByName(inputFieldName).should('be.visible');

CypressTools.getByName(inputFieldName)
  .invoke('val')
  .should('not.be.empty');
```

but I think a simple reordering will also work

```js
CypressTools.getByName(inputFieldName)
  .should('be.visible')              // check the DOM element, passes it on as subject
  .invoke('val')                     // changes subject to the text of the input
  .should('not.be.empty');           // check the text is not empty
```